# automapper map with reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, enums, automapper

i'm trying to make an automapper helper function that checks conversion of enums (where i've custom business logic in mappers)
mapper is an instance, non static.

```
var cfgExp = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
cfgExp.AddProfile<ProfileXXX>()
MapperConfiguration mapConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfgExp);
IMapper mapper = new Mapper(mapConfig);
mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
mapper.AssertEnumConversion(cfgExp);
```

```
public static void AssertEnumConversion(this IMapper @thisMapper, MapperConfigurationExpression cfgExp)
{
    try
    {
        if (@thisMapper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@thisMapper));

        List<TypePair> enumMapping = cfgExp
          .Profiles
          .SelectMany(x => x.TypeMapConfigs)
          .Where(x => x.Types.SourceType.IsEnum)
          .Select(x => x.Types)
          .ToList();


        MethodInfo methodMap = @thisMapper
            .GetType()
            .GetMethods()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Map" && x.IsGenericMethod)
            .ToList()[0];//here i've seen 6 mappers  take first //TDestination Map<TDestination>(object source)

        foreach (var item in enumMapping)
        {
            Type tSource = item.SourceType;
            Type tDest = item.DestinationType;

            //here i've an helper to take a ienumerable<Enum>
            MethodInfo method = typeof(EnumConverters).GetMethod("GetEnumValues");
            MethodInfo methodGenericSource = method.MakeGenericMethod(tSource);
            object enumsSource = methodGenericSource.Invoke(null, null);

            IEnumerable<int> enumIenumInt = enumsSource as IEnumerable<int>;
            if (enumIenumInt == null)
                throw new ApplicationException($"enumIenumInt==null ({tSource.FullName} to {tDest.FullName})");

            Array enumArray = Array.CreateInstance(tDest, enumIenumInt.Count());
            foreach (var e in enumArray)
            {
                MethodInfo methodMapGeneric = methodMap.MakeGenericMethod(tDest);
               //here i've exeption invoking...
                methodMapGeneric.Invoke(@thisMapper, new object[1] { e });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

but i receive exception like mapper is not initialized...
where i'm wrong!?!?

Comment: Which line is throwing and what is the *exact* error?

Comment: @nvoigt methodMapGeneric.Invoke(@thisMapper, new object[1] { e });

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to check? If given a certain input enum `A` the correct value `B` gets as result?

Comment: That's not the way to do it. Check [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html#custom-validations).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu i've did it in mapping. now i want a custom assertion after default AssertConfigurationIsValid

Comment: @RMH
I'm trying to find allo mapping enum to enum.
where i've custom logic (and also throwing excpetion if something is wrong or forgotten)
so now i'm finding al mapping enum to enum,
for each one i'm calling Enum.GetValues(typeof(E)).Cast<E>() to have all enums of that type,  and on each one calling iMapper.Map()

Comment: Yes, and I've linked to how it's properly done :)

Answer (score 0):

i've solved in this way

```
public static void AssertEnumConversion(this IMapper @thisMapper, MapperConfigurationExpression cfgExp)
{
    try
    {
        if (@thisMapper == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@thisMapper));
        }

        if (cfgExp == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cfgExp));
        }

        var profilesEnum = cfgExp
            .Profiles
            .Where(x => x.TypeMapConfigs.Any(y => y.SourceType.IsEnum))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.ProfileName,
                TypesEnum = x.TypeMapConfigs.Where(y => y.Types.SourceType.IsEnum).ToArray()
            })
            .ToList();

        foreach (var p in profilesEnum)
        {
            foreach (var t in p.TypesEnum)
            {
                Type tSource = t.SourceType;     //enum
                Type tDest = t.DestinationType;  //enum

                Array values = Enum.GetValues(tSource);//.Cast<E>();
                if (values == null)
                    throw new ApplicationException("values == null");

                foreach (var e in values)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        @thisMapper.Map(e, tSource, tDest);//here i need to assert conversion with automapper...
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException($"AssertEnumConversion exception (Profile:{p.ProfileName} From:{tSource.FullName} To:{tDest.FullName} On:{e})", ex);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what does this @thisMapper do?

Comment: nothing special, just typo or misleading...
in extensions methods i usually call "extended object paramenter" @this